# CSS TABLE SCRAPING

Tags: css, xml, scrape

I am able to  SCRAPING simple  data table from web to google sheet , finding difficult to scrape data from web with has multiple toggle and pulldown menu list.
Here is a site 
https://www.indiainfoline.com/markets/derivatives/futures-and-options
I want to pull table for stock futures 
Please can anyone look into this ?  As I see this is much more complicated ...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. We are to help you find a solution, but not to write the solution for you. So, what have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? Can you write a [MCVE] to show your problem?

Comment: As I am from mechanical background n don't know much about it and searched videos and some web pages regarding same but in this case seems complicated,my activity may be funny for you experts, what I have did ,in sheet in A2 link of site B2 is xpath query, as per  inspection data of site I have changed xpath query with different try and few of them .1st :- //table//tr - getting all titles but no data values,2nd:- //a[@href='/markets/derivatives/long-buildup'] Position buildup Long Build Up
Yours efforts will be inspiration for this new be .
Thanks .

Comment: I am able to scrap data from simple side but not from about given link I am sharing my shit please look into this your help will be appreciate
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BZZsvW0IjaamqRHObw9Z0ODBfPotjaw-IlCACbZTe_I/edit?usp=sharing